# Google maps javascript drawing a polyline

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am trying to draw a Polyline through Google maps. I have already gotten a path through the snap to road function, but I get it as an object, but I need an array as a path. Any idea of how to convert the path object to Array? This is the code I've gotten so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style type="text/css">
      html, body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
      #map { height: 100%; }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var map;

    function initMap() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: {lat: 65, lng: -20},
          zoom: 8
        });
        path = (64.06507, -21.57787),(64.06324000000001, -21.567200000000003),(64.06213000000001, -21.560760000000002),(64.06129, -21.555650000000004),(64.06070000000001, -21.55158);
        var geralinu = new google.maps.Polyline({
            path: path,
            strokeColor: 'Red',
            strokeOpacity: 1.0,
            strokeWeight: 2
        });
        //geralinu.setPath(lina);
        }
    </script>
    <script async defer
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyClRZNMxcuO2BSi3nynNQu7e7uFyzylWZ4&callback=initMap">
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The error I'm getting is Uncaught TypeError: Object.entries is not a function

Answer (score 0):

This is not valid javascript:

```
path = (64.06507, -21.57787),(64.06324000000001, -21.567200000000003),(64.06213000000001, -21.560760000000002),(64.06129, -21.555650000000004),(64.06070000000001, -21.55158);
```

I would suggest making an array of [google.maps.LatLngLiteral](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLngLiteral) objects (I removed some of the extra zeros at the end):

```
var path = [{lat: 64.06507,lng: -21.57787}, {lat: 64.06324,lng: -21.5672}, {lat: 64.06213,lng: -21.56076}, {  lat: 64.06129,lng: -21.55565}, {lat: 64.0607,lng: -21.55158}];
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/xqqac5ty/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var map;

function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {
      lat: 65,
      lng: -20
    },
    zoom: 8
  });
  var path = [{lat: 64.06507,lng: -21.57787}, 
              {lat: 64.06324,lng: -21.5672},
              {lat: 64.06213,lng: -21.56076}, 
              {lat: 64.06129,lng: -21.55565}, 
              {lat: 64.0607,lng: -21.55158}];
  
  var geralinu = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: path,
    strokeColor: 'Red',
    strokeOpacity: 1.0,
    strokeWeight: 2,
    map: map
  });
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  for (var i = 0; i < geralinu.getPath().getLength(); i++) {
    bounds.extend(geralinu.getPath().getAt(i));
  }
  map.fitBounds(bounds);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initMap);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```